# neo4j cypher - is 'created_at' on relationships magic?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
MATCH(u:USER) where u.id in {a_list}
MATCH(e:WHALE) # this is a singleton
CREATE (e)-[h:HARPOON]->(u)
SET h.a = 1, h.b = 2, h.created_at = {created_at}
```

So `u` can be multiple users.  `e` is a singleton. Basically we're going to relate the whale to every user.

My problem is that it works fine... if I remove `created_at` from the query. If I leave it in, not all users are related to the whale. In fact, if I simply rename the parameter name from `created_at` to `xcreated_at` it works fine.

Is there something special about `created_at`?

Answer (score 3):

`created_at` isn't special, as far as I know.  It might depend on your driver, though.  In the ruby `neo4j` gem, for instance, `created_at` is special, but not for any raw Cypher queries that you run.

Additionally, are you removing the parameter both from the query and from your parameter hash/map?  That might cause some weirdness.

Lastly, this was probably dropped because you were making an example, but just `created_at = {created_at}` won't do anything.  You need to specify the object which the property is being set on.  I assume it's the relationship in this case so you'd want: `h.created_at = {created_at}`

Comment: Thanks for the words. However, the issue has been identified as a wetware failure on my part.